# Pokemon API request generate 5 Pokémon at a time

Tags: reactjs, random, axios

I need help with how to fetch 5 random pokemon at a time instead of rendering all pokemon on the screen using react?

```
// destructuring
const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
const rootApi = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/';

// fetch Pokemon
useEffect(() => {
  const id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 800);
  const fetchItems = async (id) => {
    const response = await axios.get(rootApi + id);
    setItems([...items, response.data]);
  };
  fetchItems(id);
}, [items]);
```

Comment: tried this? `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=5`

Comment: sorry, I want to fetch 5 pokemon every time you click the button that's the plan

Comment: you can use combination of limit and offset to paginate through the api

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is exactly what you want:

Solution 1:
You can make requests on all pages and save them in a state Array. Every time you make a request on a page, you can make a spread operator on your array and add the new response. But this solution will take a long time as this api is over 1100 pages long.

Solution 2:
You can draw 5 integer values ​​(between 1 and the number of pages), and, according to the number that comes out, you make the request on the page drawn. With the response to the request, you make another sort and catch the first pokemon and store it in a state Array. Repeat this operation 4 more times, or as many times as you like. In the end, just render the array with the pokemons drawn!

At first it was these two solutions that came to my mind! If this is in line with your question, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

generate offset randomly each time, and fetch 5 pokemons it will fetch you 5 consecutive pokemons.
you can also fetch all pokemons once and randomly choose 5 indexes.
here is sample code.
codesandbox  https://codesandbox.io/s/gallant-davinci-jfutn?file=/src/App.js:0-946

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

function getUrl(limit, offset) {
  return `https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=${limit}&offset=${offset}`;
}

export default function App() {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);
  const [offset, setOffset] = useState(Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));

  const generateNewId = () => {
    const id = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    setOffset(id);
  };
  // fetch Pokemon
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchItems = async (offset) => {
      const response = await axios.get(getUrl(5, offset));
      const data = response.data;
      setItems([...items, ...data.results]);
    };
    fetchItems(offset);
  }, [offset]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      {items && items.map((item) => <p key={item.url}>{item.name}</p>)}
      <button onClick={generateNewId}>fetch 5 pokemon</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why is it that it only gives 5 random pokemon every time you click the button? What if we still want existing Pokemon and add 5 each time you click the button? 

And I notice you are not using Axios? is there any difference on fetch()?

Comment: the problem using https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=${limit}&offset=${offset} is you cant render sprites IMG and abilities just the name

Comment: fetch() is native API for HTTP request , I have updated code using axios, there is no image returned in response for https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon, what do you mean you cant render sprites IMG and abilities just the name?

Comment: Thank you so much, but what if you don't want to render 5 pokemon on the first render, only when you click the button?

Comment: then keep `fetchItems` function outside of useEffect and don’t call it inside useEffect

Comment: shubham jha, can you send you put back your old version of the code pls

Comment: Hi @GieGie , this is a very basic concept in React and JavaScript if you are not able to change the code according to your use case I would suggest that give it a few hours to understand it, you can learn basic concepts by watching YouTube tutorials in few hours. or you can learn from here https://beta.reactjs.org/learn